# Pygelf - How to send logs with "notice" severity level

Tags: python, python-3.x, graylog, graylog3

I'm using **pygelf** logging handler to integrate a Flask app with **Graylog**.

According to [documentation](https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/gelf.html?highlight=syslog#gelf-payload-specification), Graylog supports eight syslog severity levels, based on [RFC 3164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164#section-4.1.1), namely:

```
(...)
        Numerical         Severity
          Code

           0       Emergency: system is unusable
           1       Alert: action must be taken immediately
           2       Critical: critical conditions
           3       Error: error conditions
           4       Warning: warning conditions
           5       Notice: normal but significant condition
           6       Informational: informational messages
           7       Debug: debug-level messages
(...)
```

While Graylog supports level 5, which is `notice`, Python's **logging** package does not seem to have neither a `notice()` logging method (like `info()` or `debug()`) nor a corresponding logging level defined:

```
CRITICAL = 50
FATAL = CRITICAL
ERROR = 40
WARNING = 30
WARN = WARNING
INFO = 20
DEBUG = 10
NOTSET = 0
```

**Question**:
Is there a way to force `pygelf` to use the `notice` log level?

---

Additional background:

I'm using **Flask** framework, which by default uses log levels 6 (`info`) and 7 (`debug`) to log it's own internal http request data that looks like:

`101.101.101.101 - - [03/Sep/2019 14:15:55] "GET /static/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 -`

Because of those internal logs, my own `info` and `debug`-level logs get lost in the crowd. I don't want to completely filter them off, but I still want to have some distinct informative logging level that's not as high as `warning` - that's why I could use a `notice`-level logging, which unfortunately I can't use out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Pygelf internally holds a `dict`, that maps Python logging levels and their corresponding Graylog logging levels, in `gelf.py`:

```
LEVELS = {
    logging.DEBUG: 7,
    logging.INFO: 6,
    logging.WARNING: 4,
    logging.ERROR: 3,
    logging.CRITICAL: 2
}
```

---

**My solution**: In order to log on Graylog's level 5 (notify) I had to:

1. Add a new log-level mapping in the logger configuration:

```
from pygelf import GelfTcpHandler, gelf

NOTIFY = 35
GELF_NOTIFY_LEVEL = 5

(...)

gelf.LEVELS.update({NOTIFY: GELF_NOTIFY_LEVEL})
handler = GelfTcpHandler(
    ...
)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
```

2. Change the logger calls from the default methods to ones with custom log level:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

(...)

# logger.debug('Old logging to "debug"-level logger')
logger.log(NOTIFY, 'New logging to "notify"-level logger')
```